# OpenXR Runtime set to Steam is causing performance problems on Oculus Link

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, steamvr, openxr

I am developing VR game on steam using Unity 2021 and OpenXR. When OpenXR Runtime is set to Oculus like on screenshot, everything is ok, performance in game is perfect.
[image]

But when I set OpenXR Runtime on SteamVR the game is laggy as hell. I tested this on other VR games and problem does not occur, only in my game. Do you guys know what can be wrong?